# PHPWord template processing placeholder

Tags: php, phpword

I am using PHPWord to generate documents from templates, I was wondering if I can change the placeHolder format from **"${placeHolder}"** to **"<< placeHolder >>"**, Because I already have 100+ document with placeholders in this format **"<< placeHolder >>"** so it will be hard to change all of them.

Update #1:

For Example, I have a template document in the following format:

> Dear << firstName >>,
>
> It is a pleasure to send you this mail to talk about your Corporation
> << CorporationName >>...
>
> Best Regards, << senderName >>.

I want to use PHPWord to create a new document from this template and fill the placeholders variables using "setValue" method, But setValue only substitute the following format only ${placeholder}, so my question is can I make setValue substitute this << placeholder >>?

Comment: Adding an example would be helpful

Comment: @Willysatrionugroho I added some example and explanation for what I want, I hope this clarifies what I mean.

Comment: Using notepad++ you can change 100+ files at once, using regular expression.

Comment: @Heri can't open .doc or .docx with notepad++.